# Call function is not valid in contract

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, dapp-development, remix

```
contract NotifyContract { //address at 0x971A46e7C16D2bBEd2167460961D86Dc3715EE32
    address public userAddr;
    byte public types;
    function notify(byte tokenByte,address userAddr_){
        types=tokenByte;
        userAddr=userAddr_;
    } 
}
```

//

```
contract Set {
    bool public ret;
    address public tokenAddr;
    address public userAddr;
    function Set(address tokenAddr_,address userAddr_){
        tokenAddr=tokenAddr_;
        userAddr=userAddr_;
    } 
    function call1(byte bb){
        ret=tokenAddr.call("notify",bb,userAddr);   //1 not valid
    }
    function call2(byte bb){
        tokenAddr.call(bytes4(sha3("notify(byte,address)")),bb,userAddr);//2 not valid
    }
    function call3(byte bb){
        NotifyContract c=NotifyContract(tokenAddr);// valid
        c.notify(bb,userAddr);
    }
}
```

At first, I create the `NotifyContract` contract, then I create the `Set` contract and pass the `NotifyContract` address and other `userAddr_`, but the function `call` is not valid. `NotifyContract` do not have the changed value? only 3 is valid. Is there something wrong?

Comment: `byte tokenAddr_` is misleading. Because one will assume `tokenAddr_` is an address.

Comment: so sorry,I have correct it. It is strange that call function is not valid. Is something wrong??

Answer (score 3):

1. `call1` will never work.
2. If your contract name is `Set`, then the constructor function is `function Set()`. You forgot to capitalise it. `function set()` is wrong. If you make this mistake then `address public tokenAddr;` will always be `0x`.
3. `byte` is an alias for `bytes1`, so `"notify(byte,address)"` is not the canonical signature. `"notify(bytes1,address)"` is.

Comment: thank u very much.                                                                                      1. Why call1 will never work?     it actually does not work.                                                                        2.as u said , I change byte to bytes1, it works. why?

Comment: `call1` will never work because this is not how you call a function. The first 4 bytes have to be calculated as per `call2` and `"notify"` is neither 4 bytes nor correct. And the signature calculation in `call2` has to use the canonical signature. If you don't, the `sha3` is different and the function is not recognised.

Comment: If this answered your question, you might as well mark it as such. Cheers